# Copying a file, but appending index if file exists

Tags: python-3.x

I have several directories with filenames being the same, but their data inside is different.
My program identifies these files (among many others) and I would like to copy all the matches to the same directory.

I am using `shutil.copy(src,dst)` but I don't want to overwrite files that already exist in that directory (previous matches) if they have the same name. I'd like to be able to append an integer if it already exists. Similar to the behavior in Windows10 when you copy where you can "keep both versions".

So for example, if I have `file.txt` in several places, the first time it would copy into `dst` directory it would be `file.txt`, the next time it would be `file-1.txt` (or something similar), and the next time it would be `file-2.txt`.

Are there any flags for `shutil.copy` or some other copy mechanism in Python that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Duplicated. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383384/python-copy-files-to-a-new-directory-and-rename-if-file-name-already-exists or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960274/move-file-to-a-folder-or-make-a-renamed-copy-if-it-exists-in-the-destination-fol

Comment: This is also kinda related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282647/python-shutil-copy-if-i-have-a-duplicate-file-will-it-copy-to-new-location